# How to import QWebView in my QT project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake, qtwebkit

Hello there I'm creating a simple window which uses a QWebView to display web content in it.

In my mainwindow.cpp file i add: `#include <QWebView>` (also tried `#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>`)

in my .pro file I added: `QT       += webkit webkitwidgets`

But I still get a build error: QWebView: No such file or directory.

I'm using Qt Creator (Qt4) under arch linux. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think, if you use Qt4, you do not need `webkitwidgets` in your project file. Having `QT += webkit` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks... But I have some time being part of stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using Archlinux for Qt 4 purposes, and the issue is this:

```
QT += webkit webkitwidgets
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The Qt GUI was separated into QtGui and QtWidgets in Qt 5. That also included the restructuring of the QtWebKit module to reflect the changes.

Therefore, in Qt 4, there were no separate widget modules. That means, you should only write the following and that will work:

```
QT += webkit
```

Notice the `webkitwidgets` line removed. If you really fancy this, and wish to use Qt 5 later while being compatible with Qt 4, you could write this condition check:

```
QT += webkit
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):QT+=webkitwidgets
```